# Trying to add an ACF field under the post title in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

My client is using the Divi builder theme and has asked me to insert a subhead under the post title on category archive pages. The theme uses the_content() to pull all content into the pages so simply adding a line under the title in the page templates isn't an option.

This may not be the best way to do it, but I used ACF to add get_field( "region" ) and modified the code from this [github](https://gist.github.com/glueckpress/2702422). It's inserting the field where I need it, but the title is reading html as text. I have a `<br/>` in there now but would like to replace with `<span class="">`. Any idea why it's not being read as code?

[live example >](http://www.victusworldimports.com/argentina/)

Code:

```
    function gp121028_filter_title( $title ) {
    $substrings = explode( ' | ', $title );
    $title = ( ! empty( $substrings[0] ) ) ? $substrings[0] . '<br/>' . get_field( "region" ) : $title;
return $title;
```

}

Comment: In your acf region, have you chosen to format the text, and turn it into html? or is it set to "no formatting"?

Comment: Hey - thanks for the response. I ended up building the page manually for now but will be on the look out in the future. Also, I hope the fix wasn't that easy... I spent HOURS on this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasnt able to solve it - built it manualy.